# Facebook like customize post pop-up

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Hi I don't have a single idea on how to do this one. Well I need to make a like button for my page so I read about [facebook like](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) documentation. Now I already set a like button on my page but the thing is I cant customize the one that pops up when I click the like button which will brings a pop-up that can post to my wall.

Well what exactly I need to do is to set the title of that pop-up with the url under the title, a picture and a description. I tried the meta tags which said needed to be posted between the head tag but nothing happens. It just show a message that you like http://foo.com which is not the one I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer that I posted a little while ago that should shed some light on the `og:tags` : 
http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/8887746/558021

Comment: @KaHel this is your fix.  You can specify the OG tags.  Be sure to lint the url after you make changes to ensure Facebook has the latest og values.

Comment: forgot to update my question anyway I already got it yesterday. Thanks for the help. I also figured out that I need to assign the meta (og:tags) for each page and the button and link will do the rest. Thank you!